# Get the first three human readable elements in a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, view, django-templates

I'm trying to render elements in a Django view. Every clinic object has many specialities, but for estetic reasons I only want the first three of them to be displayed in the template. I've tried:

```
def clinics_index(request):
    clinics = Clinic.objects.all()
    for clinic in clinics:
        speciality = clinic.get_speciality_display
    context = {
        'clinics' : clinics,
        'speciality' : speciality,
    }
    return render(request, 'guide/clinic/clinic_directory.html', context)
```

This now renders the human-readable name of the speciality field (which is a multiple choice field in the model). However, I can't use substraction to only get 3 elements like here:

```
speciality = clinic.get_speciality_display[:3]
```

As I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /guide/clinics/
'method' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I render it?

Edit:

This is the Clinic model:

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    speciality = MultiSelectField(choices=Speciality.choices, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Cities.choices, blank=True, null=True)
    ward = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Wards.choices, blank=True, null=True)
    full_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    maps_link = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    train_access = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    bus_access = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    parking = models.CharField(_('Parking availability'), max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    english_support = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    holiday_availability = models.BooleanField(_('Availability on weekends/holidays'), default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('guide:clinic_detail', kwargs={"slug" : self.slug})
```

And the template snippet:

```
<tbody>
{% for clinic in clinics %}
<tr>
    <td>{{clinic.name}}</td>
    <td>{{clinic.city}}</td>
    <td>{{clinic.ward}}</td>
    <td>{{speciality}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{clinic.get_absolute_url}}">More...</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**EDIT:**

This code is rendering the first 3 human readable elements as I wanted:

```
clinics = Clinic.objects.all()
for clinic in clinics:
   speciality = ','.join(clinic.get_speciality_display().split(',')[:3])
```

However, I am struggling to render it correctly with its correspondant instance. This code:

```
fff = [{'name': i.name, 'speciality': ','.join(i.speciality[:3])} for i in Clinic.objects.all()]
```

Is rendering the non-human readable names. How could connect both (and also display `city` and `ward` fields for each instance)?

Comment: Add your clinic model (and speciality model?) to your question and your template where you display the clinics and specialities

Comment: I added those in the edit.

Comment: Where did you get `MultiSelectField` from? Is it from some installed package? Which version of Python, Django and this package are you using?

Comment: Yes I am using this one: https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/
Django is 4.1, Python is 3.9.15 and this package is the 0.1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in a loop you want to collect all the data. To do this, you need to save them to a list. But that's overkill, just pass `clinics` to a dictionary and iterate over all the values in the template. Also, for links, I used `clinic.slug` instead of `clinic.get_absolute_url`, since the model already returns the generated url through the `get_absolute_url` method.

views.py

```
def clinics_index(request):
    clinics = Clinic.objects.all()[:3]

    return render(request, 'guide/clinic/clinic_directory.html', {'context': clinics})
```

templates

```
{% for clinic in context %}
<p>{{ clinic }}</p>
<tr>
    <td>{{ clinic.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ clinic.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ clinic.ward }}</td>
    <td>{{ clinic.speciality }}</td>
    <td><a href="{{ clinic.slug }}">More...</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**Update 05.11.2022**
To get the clinic.get_speciality_display() value, you need to call the method using parentheses. When I print out the value type, I get a string. Therefore, in order to take the first three elements, I turn the string into a list, select the desired number and again turn it into a string.

So you can select the first three records:

```
clinics = Clinic.objects.all()
for clinic in clinics:
   speciality = ','.join(clinic.get_speciality_display().split(',')[:3])
```

all code:
views.py

```
def clinics_index(request):
    #fff = [{'name': i.name, 'speciality': i.speciality[:3]} for i in Clinic.objects.all()]#if you need to display 'speciality' as a list
    fff = [{'name': i.name, 'speciality': ','.join(i.speciality[:3])} for i in Clinic.objects.all()]

    return render(request, 'guide/clinic/clinic_directory.html', {'context': fff})
```

templates

```
<tbody>
{% for a in context %}
<tr>
    <p><td>{{ a.name }}</td></p>
    <p><td>{{ a.speciality }}</td></p>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

If that's not what you need. Show what the data looks like and what you want to see.

Comment: Rendering all the clinics in the database its fine at this moment, but I'd like to only render the first three elements of 'clinic.speciality' or the 'speciality' field. Still haven't had success with it.

Comment: @rolandist_scim do I understand you correctly that there are several specialties in each row and you want to show only the first three for each row (records from the model)? Or show an example of several rows and how you want them to be.

Comment: Yes, there are several specialities in each row and I am trying to show only 3 of them.

Comment: Try, added an option, what you want.

Comment: I would need to display the data in a template, being a different clinic every row and have its correspondant specialities in the speciality column. Your code renders the same records always, not for every specific object. Also, I would need the human readable name of it... thanks for the answer though

Comment: @rolandist_scim i don’t know if  saw the code that  updated, because I updated it several times. It seems clear to me why it doesn't work: clinic.get_speciality_display[:3] method needs to be called through parentheses. And since it's a string, create a list from it.

Comment: Actually I got what I wanted with this code:
clinics = [{'name': i.name, 'city': i.city, 'ward': i.ward, 'speciality': ','.join(i.get_speciality_display().split(',')[:3])} for i in Clinic.objects.all()]
Thank you.